# JOINING the Same Tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with 4 columns such as Customer ID, Person ID, Year, Unit Cost.

[image]

I want to join the same table with all the years from table and keep the all years for all customer ID and PErson ID's. IF there is no data in the table for respective customer ID and PErson ID then I want the Cost as NULL.
Expected Data:

[image]

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the existing data:

```
select pc.*, y.*, t.cost
from (select distinct customer, personid from customer_table) pc cross join
     (select distinct year from customer_table) y left join
     customer_table t
     on t.customer = pc.customer and t.personid = pc.personid and t.year = y.year;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried your code just replacing the source table t as customer_table t in the code but I get the errors:     saying the t and p columns could not bound.                                                                                                                                             select pc.*, y.*, t.price
from (select distinct customer, personid from customer_table t) pc cross join
     (select distinct year from customer_table t) y left join
     customer_table t
     on t.customer = pc.customer and t.personid = p.personid and t.year = y.year;